# Binary Tree array list representation

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

I have been doing some research on Binary trees, and the array list representation. I am struggling to understand that the worst case space complexity is O(2^n). Specifically, the book states, the space usage is O(N) (N = array size), which is O(2^n) in the worst case . I would have thought it would have been 2n in the worst case as each node has two children (indexes) not O(2^n), where n = no. of elements.

an example, if I had a binary tree with 7 nodes, then the space would be 2n = 14 not 2^n = 128. 
[image]

Comment: also known as `Heap`. And when you said space is (2^n), did you mean `2^height`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Heap implementation on an array. Where

```
A[1..n]
left_child(i) = A[2*i]
right_child(i) = A[2*i+1]
parent(i) = A[floor(i/2)]
```

Now, come to space. Think intuitively,

when you insert first element n=1, location=A[1], similarly,

```
n=2 @A[2] left_child(1)
n=3 @A[3] right_child(1)
n=4 @A[4] left_child(2)
n=5 @A[5] right_child(2)
```

You see, n<sup>th</sup> element will go into `A[n]`. So space complexity is `O(n)`.

When you code you just plug-in the element to be inserted in the end say at `A[n+1]`, and say that it's a child of `floor((n+1)/2)`.

Refer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Heap_implementation

---

Heap is a *nearly complete tree*, so total number of elements in the tree would be `2h-1 < n <= 2h+1-1` and this is what the length of array you will need. Refer: [this](http://code.naishe.in/2012/10/heap-and-heap-sort.html)

Answer (score 0):

The worst case space complexity of a binary tree is O(n) (not O(2^n) in your question), but using arrays to represent binary trees can save the space of pointers if it's nearly a complete binary tree.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Arrays

Answer (score 0):

I think this refers to storing *arbitrary* binary trees in an array representation, which is normally used for *complete* or *nearly complete* binary trees, notably in the implementation of heaps.

In this representation, the root is stored at index `0` in the array, and for any node with index `n`, its left and right children are stored at indices `2n+1` and `2n+2`, respectively.

If you have a degenerate tree where no nodes have any right children (the tree is effectively a linked list), then the first items will be stored at indices `0, 1, 3, 7, 15, 31, ...`. In general, the `n`th item of this list (starting from `0`) will be stored at index `2n-1`, so in this case the array representation requires `θ(2n)` space.